# Terraform v0.11.12 returns "Usage"

Tags: terraform, usage

Terraform v0.11.12 returns "Usage" when I try ./terraform plan, apply, or validate. I have main.tf, variables.tf, and terraform.tfvars files located in the same directory from where I am running ./terraform.
I've provided links to each file down below.

```
./terraform plan
Usage: terraform plan [options] [DIR-OR-PLAN]

  Generates an execution plan for Terraform.

  This execution plan can be reviewed prior to running apply to get a
  sense for what Terraform will do. Optionally, the plan can be saved to
  a Terraform plan file, and apply can take this plan file to execute
  this plan exactly.

  If a saved plan is passed as an argument, this command will output
  the saved plan contents. It will not modify the given plan.
```

```
./terraform version

Terraform v0.11.12

+ provider.external v1.1.1
+ provider.ignition v1.1.0
+ provider.null v2.1.1
+ provider.template v2.1.1
+ provider.vsphere v1.11.0
```

https://github.com/openshift/installer/blob/master/upi/vsphere/main.tf

https://github.com/openshift/installer/blob/master/upi/vsphere/variables.tf

https://github.com/openshift/installer/blob/master/upi/vsphere/terraform.tfvars.example

Answer (score 1):

You can't be in the correct directory.

You're specifying

```
./terraform plan
```

which means the terraform binary should be in the same directory as your terraform resource files, which according to your source control on Github, it is not.

Set up the `terraform` binary correctly so that it is in your `$PATH` and try again.

If you were in the correct directory, the first thing terraform should tell you is that you need to run

```
terraform init
```